# Yii2 Cookie not generating

Tags: cookies, yii2, setcookie, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to set the cookie but cookie is not getting saved. Below is what I have tried:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
        'name' => 'abc',
        'value' => 'xyz',
        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
]));

$cookies1 = Yii::$app->request->cookies;

if ($cookies1->has('abc'))
        $cookieValue = $cookies1->getValue('abc');

echo 'value : '.$cookieValue;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE);
```

$cookieValue does not hold any value. Cookie isn't generated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Your problem is that you are trying to set and then get the cookie **in the same request**.

Your browser has not yet received the response, so it has not had the chance to add the cookie before you try to read it out.

You just need to set and then fetch the cookie in separate requests:

```
public function actionSetCookie() {

    $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

    $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
        'name' => 'abc',
        'value' => 'xyz',
        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
    ]));

    echo 'Cookie set!';
}

public function actionGetCookie() {

    $cookies1 = Yii::$app->request->cookies;

    if ($cookies1->has('abc'))
        $cookieValue = $cookies1->getValue('abc');

    echo 'value : '.$cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: I have done that way only. I set the cookie in controller action and then in my rendered view header I tried printing the cookie value. But the first time it does not hold any value when I refresh the page then cookie contained the value.

Comment: you're not understanding me exactly, you need **seperate** requests. Executing code in the controller and then rendering a view **is still the same request**.

Answer (score 0):

`Set your cookie like this`

```
$cookie = Yii::$app->response->cookies;

$cookie = new \yii\web\Cookie
  ([
        'name' => 'abc',
        'value' => 'xyz',
        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
  ]);

Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);

//check cookie is exist or not

if(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('abc'))
{
     // if exist then get cookie value
     $username =  Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('abc');
}
```

Comment: Hi Vidya. The problem was not related to creation/setting of cookie. I was setting and accessing the value of the cookie in the same request, which is not possible. As mentioned by @deacs you need separate request for accessing the value of the cookie. Anyway thanks for answering!

Comment: Well , Your issue is resolved that's the main thing . But I am setting and accessing the cookies in the same function. So I want to tell you that it is possible in same function ,try it once.

Comment: Ok. Will try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just putting here my answer, as several time visited this question but could not find solution. I spent one whole day to solve it. So hope this answer will help someone.

In my case I've used `axios` package which sent request from frontend and I got response `Set-Cookie` in the header but not saved in the browser. So setting `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;` solved my issue.